# Правила транскрибирования слов латиницей

Tags: общие-вопросы, транскрипция

Здравствуйте! Необходимо составить транскрипцию слов не кириллическими буквами, как учат в русских школах, а латиницей, как делают в высших учебных заведениях. Между тем я нигде не могу отыскать, как это сделать.

Расскажите про общие принципы транскрибирования латиницей (или дайте ссылку на таковые). Буду признательна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ййесть!!! Я нашла, как ОНО правильно называется, и - выгуглилось! Но это не "транскрибирование латиницей", лишь с некоторыми её элементами.

> Для того чтобы как можно точнее записать звучащую речь, используют
> **фонетический транскрипт**.
>
> В фонетической транскрипции используют
> буквы традиционного алфавита, при этом запись ведётся по особым
> неорфографическим законам. В дополнение к буквам используют
> диакритические символы...

"**[Лекция 7. Фонетическая транскрипция](http://kpfu.ru/docs/F1773831677/Kamalova.L.A.Lekciya._7.Fonetika.pdf)**" дана в формате PDF: муторно копировать, но по ссылке - всё есть, все знаки!

---

Постскриптум. В источнике (лекции) не все знаки правильно конвертировались...

[Существует несколько вариантов фонемы «а» в русской фонологии: ʌ, æ, ɑ
и а.](http://fonetica.philol.msu.ru/nn/n22.htm)... Надо искать тексты вот с такими знаками.

---

[Основные правила транскрипции](http://morfema.ru/publ/15-1-0-3) - может, там всё и ничего (по сути), да ошибки в русском. (((

---

**Русская фонетическая транскрипция**

§ 37. Транскрипция, применяемая в современной русистике, строится на базе кириллического алфавита, принятого в русской орфографии, с добавлением некоторых букв из других алфавитов.

**Знаки фонетической транскрипции**

§ 38. В транскрипции используются два вида знаков:

• буквенные, значение которых относительно конкретно, потому что каждая буква обычно соответствует определенному звукотипу, и

• диакритические – специальные условные знаки, употребляемые вместе с буквой (вверху, внизу, справа или слева от нее), образующие с ней единую транскрипционную графему и имеющие более общее, абстрактное значение дополнительного оттенка звучания. Значение диакритики должно быть одним и тем же независимо от того, к какому буквенному знаку она относится.

(Далее подряд - по параграф 48.)

**[источник](http://www.philol.msu.ru/%7Eruslang/data/pdf/7.pdf)**

Comment: Ура! Хоть кто-то что-то нашёл, моей благодарности нет конца)).